# Howto merge two arrays with values from array2 that are in 1?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array with allowed values and an array with given values.

Howto merge two arrays with values from array2 that are in 1?

```
allowed_values => ["one", "two", "three"]
given_values => ["", "one", "five", "three", "seven"]

...

expected_values => ["one", "three"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the array intersection, and you can obtain it via [the `&` operator](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-26):

> Set Intersection—Returns a new array containing elements common to the two arrays, with no duplicates.

```
[ 1, 1, 3, 5 ] & [ 1, 2, 3 ]   #=> [ 1, 3 ]
```

Comment: Its php, but thanks for the tip on intersection. Found `[ 1, 1, 3, 5 ] & [ 1, 2, 3 ]   #=> [ 1, 3 ]` from the ruby docs

Comment: Err, wow. I somehow just assumed PHP despite the obvious Ruby code. I can only attribute this to having been awake less than 10 minutes. Apologies and I'm glad I at least gave you "array intersection" to Google.